# CSS positioning help text in a form

Tags: html, css

I need to place help text below labels and finding it tricky getting the CSS correct for it.

I have created the jsfiddle below as an example.

The requirements are:

1. The label is left aligned
2. The help text is shown directly below it
3. The input and select controls appear on the same line

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/paSR2/2/

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check,

http://jsfiddle.net/paSR2/4/

**Changes**

```
label {
display: block;
font-size: .9em;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 52px; <----- /*changed*/
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px
}
```

**Without hard coded width**

```
label {
display: block;
font-size: .9em;
float: left;
clear: left;
margin: 0px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to go hard coding label widths. They're not all going to be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly rejigged your code and css, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/paSR2/9/

Comment: Nearly but the controls should be in line with the label not the help text

Answer (score 1):

I Made some modifications to your design:

http://jsfiddle.net/paSR2/13/

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I could accept multiple answers this would be one, Sumesh just got a little closer without changing my markup too much